# Resizing a PNG's dimensions (Length x Width)

Tags: image, file-format, image-formats

Alright, I will provide specifically what I need. I am using Windows 7. I need this done on a .PNG extension file. Rightclick any png file and click Properties. Under the 'Details' tab it shows the images' dimensions, the width and height in pixels.

I have tried every editor but photoshop which I do not have to create an image with a height of 23552. I use pixlr editor until I can get photoshop located at https://pixlr.com/editor/. Inside the editor I can have an image loaded which I am editing. Using that web application I can resize the image by going to 'Image' tab and pressing 'Canvas size...'. It restricts the height to 4000, but I need it 23552. The reason I need it that high is because when you animate a minecraft texture in a Resource Pack, it detects stacked images by height in the same png, not sure exactly but I know how to animate them with minecraft, I just need a way to get a 23552 pixel height on a png image. Thanks for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Paint. In Paint, open your image and click "resize" on the Home tab. Enter your desired height and save the photo.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/resize-a-picture-using-paint

Comment: Thank you so much! I am sorry for not thinking of this earlier. I feel dumb as people would say :/